# Why is XLOOKUP still returning 0 despite a specified value for the if_not_found parameter?

Tags: excel, xlookup

I have the following formula to search for the status of a same ID but for last week.

```
=XLOOKUP (1,([@[Last Week]]=[Week])*([@[Circuit ID]]=[Circuit ID]),[Current Status],"None")
```

I am very clearly specifying "None" as the if_not_found value, but despite this two rows show up with 0. All other have "None" where no match appears.

Is this a glitch?

Comment: Then the search value is found, but the return value is either 0 or blank.  The error capture is only when the search value is not found.

Comment: Ohhh so a previous isblank or if to handle blanks or 0s will solve it right?

Comment: sure, instead of `[Current Status]` put `IF([Current Status]="","None",[Current Status])`